# multiple value from associated table in sequelize and postgres

Tags: node.js, angular, postgresql, sequelize.js

Hi I am trying to link steps table and user table in my postgres db

```
User.hasMany(models.Steps, {
  foreignKey: "stepId",
  as: "steps"
});
```

and steps model has

```
Steps.belongsTo(models.User, {
  as: "user",
  foreignKey: "stepId"
});
```

and in my user service inside the findall I am using

```
include: [
{
            model: Steps,
            as: "steps",
            all: true,
            required: true
          }
        ],
        where: {
          id: req.query.id
        },
        raw: true,
        nest: true
]
```

which results in the following response

```
{
    "status": "success getUserById getUserById",
    "message": null,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "rsdfsa",
            "age": 24,
            "height": "5.8",
            "weight": "40.5",
            "createdAt": "2020-03-03",
            "updatedAt": "2020-03-03",
            "steps": {
                "stepId": 5,
                "steps": "29",
                "createdAt": "2020-03-03",
                "updatedAt": "2020-03-03"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "rsdfsa",
            "age": 24,
            "height": "5.8",
            "weight": "40.5",
            "createdAt": "2020-03-03",
            "updatedAt": "2020-03-03",
            "steps": {
                "stepId": 5,
                "steps": "34",
                "createdAt": "2020-03-03",
                "updatedAt": "2020-03-03"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there a way to get only one user with all the steps related to that user included, Please guide me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was I did not have the foreign key in the steps table, I was using the stepId as primary key but there was no userId column. Once I changed that, it is working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use group by clause to group all the steps which belong to the same user as follows -

```
include: [
  {
    model: Steps,
    as: 'steps',
    all: true,
    required: true
  }
],
where: {
  id: req.query.id
},
group: ['id', '`steps`.`stepId`'],
subQuery: false
```

Comment: Hi  Soham, there was no userId(foreign key) column in the steps table. It is working now

Comment: @sandeep, Glad to know that you have fixed it yourself.